# How to show tags in posts with a theme that does not do it

Tags: themes, tags

For my wordpress site I bought a theme, but I discovered later that this particular theme does not show posts' tags (in posts' pages). Is it possible to force the theme to show tags in posts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter `the_content`, and add the result of `get_the_tag_list()`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() )
        $content .= get_the_tag_list( '<p>Tags: ', ', ', '</p>' );

    return $content;
});
```

The other option is to create a child theme and add `the_tags()` where you need it in a template.

Comment: I am already working on a child theme running _locally_ on my computer, indeed. Thank you for answering it :)